# Vertically align text in textarea

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to find a solution to have the text typed in a textarea centered horizontally and vertically. Horizontally works fine with `text-align: center;` but centering vertically is much more of a hassle. It seems that the solution is using padding, but when the text is 3 lines high for example, the text is not  centered anymore. In my fiddle below, I have placed a red line which is the center of my textarea. I would need this to be the center of where text will appear. Even if it is 1,2,3,4 or five lines high. So if I have 4 lines of text, the red line would need to be in between lines 2 and 3.

I am wondering if there might not be a work around this with jquery?

[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adrienboufflet/9hbfgakn/)

Comment: just a remark, you inversed the usage of vertically and horizontally...currently your problem is with vertical centering, not horizontal.

Comment: Just a little tip: Instead of writing "type text here" in the element itself, you could use "<text-area placeholder="type text here">", which looks much better and also doesnt have the need to delete the text before typing

Answer (score 13):

I've come up with what I think is a very simple solution, which modifies the top padding as you type.

`padding-top` should always equal `height/2 - font-size`.  Also, use **[box-sizing: border-box;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)** to avoid problems with the default styling that's applied to textarea elements.

**jQuery**

```
$('.mytext').on('input', function() {
  var h= this.offsetHeight;
  $(this).css({   //clear current padding and height so we can use scrollHeight below
    paddingTop: 0,
    height: 0
  });

  $(this).css({
    paddingTop: Math.max(0, h/2 - this.scrollHeight/2),
    height: h
  });
});
```

```js
$('.mytext')
  .on('input', function() {
    var h = this.offsetHeight;
    $(this).css({
      paddingTop: 0,
      height: 0
    });

    $(this).css({
      paddingTop: Math.max(0, h / 2 - this.scrollHeight / 2),
      height: h
    });
  })
  .trigger('input')
  .focus();
```

```css
.mytext {
  resize: none;
  width: 280px;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="mytext" placeholder="type text here"></textarea>
```

Comment: A nice start, but when the text reaches the point where scrolling occurs (meaning you've completely filled the textbox and then some), the padding at the top seems inappropriate.

Comment: This is a really great solution. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code snippet, it might solve your problem :

http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/gICqd

It relies on CSS and a wrapper div :

```
#wrap {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 70%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#wrap .area {
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#wrap textarea.area {
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px dotted blue;
  background: transparent;
}

#wrap .dummy {
  left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @ibiza - In response to "*woah woah calm down*", please keep in mind that many users [vote only on the answer's initial state](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277157/211627). Relatively few users come back to see if the answer has been improved.

Comment: @JDB: Your assumptions based on linked meta are only true for the first minutes when answers start pouring in. But even though users **always** vote on the **latest** answer version. For instance today 2016 and this answer is almost a year old but I sure as hell won't be going and looking at it's original version. I'll just check it out as it currently is. Many users tend to practice *fastest gun on the west* You write just sufficient info initially to keep votes coming to you and then gradually improve your answer with additional details if it looks that your answer is best.

Comment: @Robert - yes, you are correct. I was addressing a specific comment in a specific context at a specific moment in time. It would have been more accurate to say "many voters vote only on the state the answer was in when they first encountered it." I apologize if my language was confusing and offended you.

Comment: @JDB It didn't offend me. I just stated what ibiza should've said after your second comment. Nevermind. :)